# Mocked HttpMessageHandler throws exception on second call

Tags: c#, .net, moq, xunit

I'm writing tests using XUnit and Moq and I'm trying to mock an HttpClient. Calling the client works the first time but the second time it throws an ObjectDisposedException when trying to read the response content. If I replace the ReadFromJsonAsync with ReadAsStringAsync it works as intended. Why do I get this exception and how do I make it possible to do multiple calls?

```
[Fact]
public async Task Test()
{
    var mockMessageHandler = new Mock<HttpMessageHandler>();

    mockMessageHandler.Protected()
        .Setup<Task<HttpResponseMessage>>("SendAsync",
            ItExpr.IsAny<HttpRequestMessage>(),
            ItExpr.IsAny<CancellationToken>())
        .ReturnsAsync(new HttpResponseMessage
        {
            StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK,
            Content = new StringContent("{\"message\": \"Hello!\"}")
        });

    using var mockHttpClient = new HttpClient(mockMessageHandler.Object);
    mockHttpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://mockurl.com");

    var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "test");

    var res = await mockHttpClient.SendAsync(request);
    var response = await res.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<ResponseMessage>();

    Console.WriteLine("Response 1: " + response.Message);

    var request2 = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "test");

    var res2 = await mockHttpClient.SendAsync(request2);
    var response2 = await res2.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<ResponseMessage>(); // <-- Throws ObjectDisposedException exception

    Console.WriteLine("Response 2: " + response2.Message);
}

private class ResponseMessage
{
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're probably getting this error because of your `using` on the `HttpClient`. Try to avoid using `using` on `HttpClient`, and prefer using a `static HttpClient`.

You can find more information about the issues with `HttpClient` class in using here :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests#issues-with-the-original-httpclient-class-available-in-net

And here a way to fix it using a `static HttpClient` : https://www.aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong#The-Fix-is-In

Comment: But why does it work when replacing ReadFromJsonAsync with ReadAsStringAsync? Why does that make a difference?